# MySQL multiple tables vs rows

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have read many posts on here about this discussion but my question is specific.

Please read in entirety before replying.

I am wondering whether it is best to have potentially hundreds if not thousands of rows in a database or to split it across multiple tables.

The scenario is:
I have a user who can be in ONE AND ONLY ONE city at a time. (There are multiple cities e.g. Paris, Berlin and London)
Now in each city are lots of areas (potentially several hundred). 
I was thinking that giving each city its own table would be more efficient.

E.G:
rooms_london
 - All areas of london in here as rows
rooms_berlin 
- all areas of berlin in here as rows

And so on for Paris and any other cities that I add in future.

Then in PHP I could construct a query similar to:

```
 SELECT * FROM rooms_$playerCity WHERE roomID = $playerRoom
```

Is this an efficient method or should I just add an extra column to a central rooms table.

If I've not been clear enough I will do my best to clarify anything that you need.

Many Thanks

Comment: *"The scenario is: I have a user who can be in ONE AND ONLY ONE city at a time."* Try using DISTINCT.

Comment: Are you asking how to build the tables and relationships to handle this scenario?  If you are limited to working with a schema that has already been built, please share the definitions for the User (player), City and Area tables.

Comment: It would most certainly NOT be more efficient to create a separate table for each city.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM rooms_$playerCity WHERE roomID = $playerRoom` beware of SQL injection

Comment: @ImreL I would use the proper escaping sequences etc to prevent injection.
bisvel I'm not stuck to an existing schema it's a new system I'm building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not split rooms into different tables.

If performance becomes a problem I would use partitioning http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html

```
+------+          +------+
| City | 1 ---- * | Room |
+------+          +------+
```

> whether ... thousands of rows in a database or to split it across
>   multiple tables.

performance will not be a problem before few million rows with complex queries and insufficient indexing

Comment: I never came across partioning before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MY SQL but my SQL Server table design would look like this

```
Create Table Player (
  PlayerID int
  ...
  )

 Create Table City (
   CityID int
   ...
  )

 Crate Table Rooms (
  RoomID int
  CityID int
  ...
  )

  Create Table PlayerRoom (
    PlayerID int
    RoomID int
    ChaeckIn DateTime
    CheckOut DateTime
    ...
    )
```

[image]

Then to get the last player in a room you could query by

```
  Select Top 1 * from PlayerRoom where Roomid = @roomID order by CheckIn Desc
```